# GUI app for sending emails through specific smtp servers

Tags: gui, software-rec, smtp, privacy

Anyone know of an application like [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) but with a **GUI**?

Preferably the application would have auto resolve of MX for the recipient domain.

The purpose would be to be able to manually send email directly to an MX, to preserve anonymity by using anonymous sender addresses (like *@hmamail.com*) when sending email to vendors etc who might use your email addresses for (unrelated) commercial purposes.